# Deny script from client, but use locally

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file - looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

<FilesMatch ^.*\.php.*$>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule ^help$ scripts/help.php [L]
#more rewrites here...
```

What I'd like to be able to do is allow a URL such as `http://example.com/help` to be rewritten (as per the rule there) and handled by the help.php script in the scripts directory, but at the same time, deny people from directly running the script by using `http://example.com/scripts/help.php`. The problem is, when I use these statements, both URLs return a 403 Forbidden. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible...

Unfortunately, I cannot place files outside/above of the root web directory (which is why I'm asking this), nor do I have access to the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/help` is requested, it gets rewritten to `/scripts/help.php` internally that then fulfills the pattern of `<FilesMatch>`. That’s why the access to `/help` is also forbidden.

But you can use mod_rewrite to only forbid the access to `/scripts/help.php` if it was requested directly by checking the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/? \]
RewriteRule .*\.php.*$ - [F]
```

Here `^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/? \]` tests whether there is a `.php` in the requested URI path (it might only be preceded by any character except `?` and a space) and is either followed by a `/` (path segment separator), a `?` (indicator for the URI query) or a space (end of the URI).